# Fowarding meeting request - are original recipients copied?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I forwarded a meeting request to someone (person A). In my sent items folder, person A is the only person listed in "To". However, when I open the sent message I see that person A is now listed as a "required" person along with all of the other original recipients of the meeting request. The message says it is from "me sent on behalf of the original meeting organizer". And, it shows the text that I added to the "Description" section, which I intended only to be seen by person A. I am using MS outlook 2007.

When I forwarded the meeting request to person A and added text to the Description section, did it copy all the other original recipients of the meeting request?

Answer (score 1):

The person you addressed it to is the only person who received it. Because you are not the meeting originator, you can not add invitees to the meeting. So when you forwarded the request, all it's done was send a copy to the person you forwarded it to.

If you want that person invited to the meeting, you will need to contact the meeting originator to have them add that person.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I understand that the meeting originator will get a notification when I forward the meeting request. Will the meeting originator get to see the texts I added to the "description" section of my forwarded meeting request? Or is the meeting orignator only notified that the meeting request was forwarded by me to person A and he cannot see the texts I added to the "description" section?

Comment: When you forward the meeting it only goes to the person(s) you send it to. As far as I know, the originator can not see the forwarded email to person A.

Answer (score -1):

Nope, should be send on behalf of.  I found that say situation, and the CalendarRepairDisable was set to $true.  Once switched back to $false it is fixed.